# Using complex types in RedisTypedClient (ServiceStack Redis)

Tags: redis, servicestack

I have an example where I want to store an object into Redis.

```
class CyPoint
    {
        // Fields...
        private bool _Done;
        private string _Color;
        private string _Position;
        private long _Id;

        public long Id
        {
            get { return _Id; }
            set
            {
                _Id = value;
            }
        }

        public string Position
        {
            get { return _Position; }
            set
            {
                _Position = value;
            }
        }

        public string Color
        {
            get { return _Color; }
            set
            {
                _Color = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Done
        {
            get { return _Done; }
            set
            {
                _Done = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

I am using this code to store the data

```
var redisCyPoint = redis.As<CyPoint>();
            var cpt = new CyPoint
            {
                Id = redisCyPoint.GetNextSequence(),
                Position = "new Vector3(200, 300, 0)",
                Color = "new Vector3(.5f, .7f, .3f)",
            };

            redisCyPoint.Store(cpt);
```

This works as I am storing strings.  But when I change position and color to Vector3 (which is: float, float, float) it only saves 0's.  It seems that the Store will not work with complex types.  Is this a limitation or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struct's are [serialized as a single scalar string value](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#c-structs-and-value-types) as returned by `ToString()`. You can implement [custom support for Structs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#custom-serialization) by implementing a constructor `Vector3(string)` that can populate itself from its `ToString()` value, or implement a static `ParseJson(string)` method.

Otherwise you can specify custom serializer to handle the serialization, e.g:

```
JsConfig<Vector3>.SerializeFn = v => "{0},{1},{2}".Fmt(v.X,v.Y,v.Z);
JsConfig<Vector3>.DeSerializeFn = s => {
    var parts = s.Split(',');
    return new Vector3(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2]);
};
```